# I want to add <br> to a div text using jQuery, but it kept showed <br> instead of newline. How can I do that?

Tags: jquery

The code is like this:

```
$('#description').text(info + '<br>' + footnote);
```

But instead of:

```
Welcome to the website!
Copyright (c) 2015
```

It shows:

```
Welcome to the website!<br>Copyright (c) 2015
```

If I change `'<br>'` to `'\n'`, then it displayed as nothing (white space)

```
Welcome to the website! Copyright (c) 2015
```

How can I add newline to a div using jQuery? Thanks.

Comment: Use `html` instead of `text`. `$('#description').html(info + '<br>' + footnote);`

Comment: Not exact duplicate, but can help to understand what the issue is and how it can be solved. Add comments if you think this should not be closed/reopened or find more appropriate dupe.

Comment: use `.html()` change `.text()`

Comment: I've tried to searched before I asked, and found some answers with `.text()` in it, but couldn't quite find the answer to my problem, hence I asked it here. I'm aware that this might already have answers, because I think this is basic, but it's hard to find answers for this particular issue because of so many questions with similar title.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

That is because you are using [`.text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/), which will escape any HTML tags in it (emphasis my own):

> We need to be aware that this method **escapes the string provided as necessary so that it will render correctly in HTML**. To do so, it calls the DOM method `.createTextNode()`, **does not interpret the string as HTML**.

Use [`.html()`](http://api.jquery.com/html/) instead:

```
$('#description').html(info + '<br>' + footnote);
```

Comment: Thank you! I never use `.html()` so I wasn't aware there's such a function in jQuery.

Comment: However, .html() need precautions as script can be passed easily